# Inverters in parallel. Forcing one to be in phase with other?

Tags: inverter, parallel

I have two cheap 800 watt (continuous) power inverters. Input is 12v AC. Output is 120v 60hz modified sine wave AC. I would like to run these in parellel to achieve 1600 watts. I have one already opened up because I had to change fuses. It seems to be a reletively straight forward circuit. It looks like an H-bridge... with 4 sets of 4 200 watt mosfets (irf640s possibly but I'll have to check). 2 sets are different from the other two, so I imagine they have p channels in there rather than 4 sets of n channel. Instead of going to all the trouble of having a microcontroller sense the zero crossings of the other and time it out and what not, would it be somewhat reasonable to just parallel all the non-IC components together like the mosfets, transformers, and rectifiers(Oh and the transformers are quite small, so I'm guessing the diodes rectify mains first,  then the iCs pulse high frequency dc thru them)? If I understand this all correctly (which I'm not sure I do, hence this posted question), the effective gate-source capacitance will now have doubled,  so the current capability of that which drives them must be considered,  as inadiquate current in that regard might make the transition from OFF to ON too long, causing unnessesary heat. Anyways, am I on the right track? What are the obstacles I will likely face that I am not seeing? I am posting this from phone so I apologize if there are spelling or grammatical errors. Thanks! -kurt

Comment: your only neglecting control system stability margin part. for gain and phase margin with a shared output....now with reduced loop gain and more disturbance usually extra loops with special compensation is needed with extra sensing

Comment: If you do manage to force the voltage loops in paralell and not have cross conduction between the two, I would be impressed. Do they have constant current limit or do they just shut down at overcurrent/overload? If they don't limit it, you are only relying on the leakage inductance in the transformers and all resistance to balance the load across them. My advice, buy a 1600 W one.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I got pretty sick late last night from welding what I now think was probably galvanized pipe in a poorly ventilated area... slept most the day. @tony I'm going to have to read about the issues with loop gain you mention. I'm not really familiar with any specifics of it. I imagine though that it is used by the IC's to make adjustments in real time. So by adding double everything in parallel, it will be making adjustments off of feedback that isn't accurate? Thanks for your response.

Comment: @winny What exactly do you mean by voltage loops and cross conduction? I do not know if they have a constant current limit. It does shut down at some point from an overload (red light and annoying beep), although I am unaware of the means that this is achieved. Are you saying that the two transformers in one unit might not be the same impedence/xr ratio as the two in the other (all they cared about was two like ones got paired, not that all pairs from every unit were the same), and this would make the load sharing be uneven? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It has been my experience with OEM SMPS designed for current sharing, that even with the currents perfectly balanced they need at least a 10% min load for stability. Now for AC current sharing, there are dynamic effects and if the Zout is high, load regulation is poor, but then power sharing is more stable with more feedback. When error levels are low from step loads, the feedback is low and this can lead to stability challenges for wide control range stability with wide load variations.

Comment: @KurtOstrom Both inverters (very likley but there are obscure examples which are entierly open loop) have their own voltage loop for regulating the output voltage. Think two thermostats in the same room, one for heating and one for AC, with both fighting each other. That's why you need to join them. If it shuts down, you do not have a constant current limit. It will be nearly impossible to make them work in paralell unless you redesign the control circuit in both from scratch. Buy a 1600 W inverter!

Comment: @winny I see! Good analogy. I appreciate the help. If you want to officially answer the question I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both inverters have their own voltage loop for regulating the output voltage (very likley but there are obscure examples which are entierly open loop). If you don't have the loops in unison/one loop for both, you end up with a simular sutuation to two thermostats in the same room, one for heating and one for AC, with both fighting each other. That's why you need to join them.

If the inverter shuts down at overload, you do not have a constant current limit. Without this functionality it will be nearly impossible to make them work in paralell unless you redesign the control circuit in both from scratch, for both CC limit and one loop for both. If you *do* pull that off, I would be very impressed and you should have no problem finding a job in the power electronics industry.

TL;DR: Buy a 1600 W inverter!